# Includes + Changes on Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: gitlab, yaml, cicd

I've been having issues with Gitlab CI/CD to run some pipelines when a file changes.

If I have only change in `folder1`, then that pipeline runs.
If I have only change in `folder2`, then that pipeline runs.
If I have changes in both folders, only second pipeline would run.

Current setup

```
include:
  - local: 'folder1/.gitlab-ci.yml'
    rules:
      - changes:
          paths:
            - folder1/**/*
          compare_to: master
        when: always
include:
  - local: 'folder2/.gitlab-ci.yml'
    rules:
      - changes:
          paths:
            - folder2/**/*
          compare_to: master
        when: always
```

Also tried with nested include, but not successful.

```
include:
  - local..
  - local..
```

Would you have any clue on where I'm doing this setup wrong?

Comment: What about this, exactly, is not working? Can you give an example of the unexpected behavior and what you expect the correct behavior to be?